# lolcat + motd = no colours

Tags: debian, ssh, colors, motd

I can't get `lolcat` to show colours in the message of the day (motd).

When I run this in the command line, all works fine:

```
exec /usr/games/fortune | /usr/games/cowsay -f moose | /usr/games/lolcat
```

But the same line in `/etc/update-motd.d` produced black-and-white output only.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, lolcat does not produce colors when its output is not a tty.

To force colors, use the `-f, --force` option:

```
/usr/games/fortune | /usr/games/cowsay -f moose | /usr/games/lolcat -f
```

This works on my system.

Comment: Thanks so much, Nick. You've nailed it!